# Is it possible to add a smiley in the message NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, plist

Is it possible to put a unicode smiley in the authorization message `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` registered in the plist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, this is how it looks when I put the following lines into my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Unicode is cool ☺</string>
```

[image]